# How to configure CruiseControl.NET to execute build for every SVN commit

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I a trying to revamp our build server system. Previously, we configured our CC.NET to build every 2 hours with all the SVN changes that was checked in prior to that period. Now, we have developed some Python code to do regression testing after the project is built. Thus, we wanted to change to a system that fires a build request for each SVN commits and run the testing afterwards.

I am stuck at the trigger part, because beside urlTrigger, CruiseControl.NET is not providing any other means to do this, as far as I know. I tried urlTrigger as well, but when my static HTML page hosted elsewhere change, a new build is not triggered.

The config i used for trigger:

```
<triggers>
  <urlTrigger url="http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~U0909093/index.html" seconds="0" buildCondition="ForceBuild"/>
</triggers>
```

**Update:** after some research, CC.NET 1.7 does not support this feature yet. The best you can do is to reduce the amount of time for interval trigger to very small value

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to check svn for changes, you want an interval trigger set to the amount of time it waits between checks

```
    <triggers>
        <intervalTrigger seconds="90" />
    </triggers>
```

Then you will need a sourcecontrol block to specify which section(s) to monitor

Answer (score 1):

Try the "IfModificationExists" feature of the [interval trigger](http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/Interval%20Trigger.html)

This will require the source control block as well.